# Drupal install on remote mysql

Tags: mysql, drupal, installation, remote-server

I am trying to install drupal on remote mysql server. I have created the user in mysql and granted the the privileges.

I am able to connect through command line from my web server like this "mysql -u xxxx -h 10.xxx.yy.zz3 -p".

But when I tried to install drupal I get "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost'". I have given the privileges for "xxxx"@"10.xxx.yy.zz3" but drupal appends localhost instead of IP to user name. I have changed settings.php to mysql server IP.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of editing the `settings.php` file, try the following:

The third screen during installation (*Database configuration*) let you set up the database on a remote MySQL server.  To do so, expand *Advanced options* and enter the database host.

I cannot guarantee that this will work, but this is how I set up Drupal to use a remote MySQL server, and I have never had this problem.  Btw, I always use the canonical domain name (e.g. `mysql.example.org`) and not the IP-address.